# ¿Cómo insertar mediante una API con PHP y Ajax cuando hay un valor autoincrementable como llave primaria?

Tags: php, ajax

Haciendo un insert mediante metodo POST con ajax surge un problema al insertar a un nuevo directivo tengo distribuidos los archivos de la siguiente manera
En primer lugar el html

```
<form action="javascript:void(0);" method="post">
                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="clave_dir">Dependencia cargo</label>
                          <select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="clave_dir" id="clave_dir">
                            <option value="0" selected>--Elige una dependencia--</option>
                            <?php
                            while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($depe_aper)){
                                echo "<option value=".$row['ac_depe'].">".$row['ac_ciclo']."-".$row['direccion']."</option>";
                            }
                            ?>

                          </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Ingresa el nombre completo">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="puesto">Cargo</label>
                        <select class="form-control" required name="puesto" id="puesto">
                            <option selected>--Elegir cargo--</option>
                            <option value="COORDINADORA">COORDINADORA</option>
                            <option value="COORDINADOR">COORDINADOR</option>
                            <option value="COORDINADORA ACADEMICA">COORDINADORA ACADEMICA</option>
                            <option value="COORDINADOR ACADEMICO">COORDINADOR ACADEMICO</option>
                            <option value="COORDINADORA GENERAL">COORDINADORA GENERAL</option>
                            <option value="COORDINADOR GENERAL">COORDINADOR GENERAL</option>
                            <option value="DIRECTORA">DIRECTORA</option>
                            <option value="DIRECTOR">DIRECTOR</option>
                            <option value="ENCARGADA DE LA DIRECCION">ENCARGADA DE LA DIRECCION</option>
                            <option value="ENCARGADO DE LA DIRECCION">ENCARGADO DE LA DIRECCION</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="plaza">Plaza</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="plaza" id="plaza" placeholder="">
                            <small class="form-text text-muted">Help text</small>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="f_ocupar">Fecha de nombramiento</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="f_ocupar" id="f_ocupar">
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" id="btn_agregar" onclick="agregar_dir();" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/directivos.js"></script>
```

A continuación el archivo de JS

```
url = "../config/directivos.php";
function agregar_dir(){
var nombre = $('#nombre').val();
var puesto = $('#puesto').val();
var plaza = $('#plaza').val();
var f_ocupar = $('#f_ocupar').val();
var clave_dir = $('#clave_dir').val();
document.getElementById('btn_agregar').innerHTML='Agregando...';

var datosEnviar = JSON.stringify({nombre:nombre, puesto:puesto, plaza:plaza, f_ocupar:f_ocupar, clave_dir:clave_dir});
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type:"POST",
    data:datosEnviar,
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(status){
        alert("Creación exitosa");
        document.getElementById('btn_agregar').innerHTML='Agregar';
    },
    error: function(status){
        alert("Registro erróneo");
        console.log(status);
        console.log(datosEnviar);
        document.getElementById('btn_agregar').innerHTML='Agregar';
    }
});
}
```

y por último el archivo donde se inserta en la bd

```
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
require 'bd.php';

switch($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]){
   case 'POST':
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    //$id_dir = $data -> id_dir; ESTE ES LA VARIABLE AUTOINCREMENTABLE
    $nombre = $data -> nombre;
    $puesto = $data -> puesto;
    $plaza = $data-> plaza;
    $f_ocupar = $data -> f_ocupar;
    $clave_dir = $data -> clave_dir;

    $insert = pg_prepare($conn,"insertar_dir" ,"INSERT INTO directivos (nombre, puesto, plaza, f_ocupar, clave_dir) VALUES($1,$2,$3,$4,$5)");
    if(!empty($clave_dir) and !empty($plaza)){
        $dire_bus=pg_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM directivos WHERE plaza='$plaza' and clave_dir='$clave_dir' ");
        $result = pg_fetch_assoc($dire_bus);
        if($result == False){
            $insert = pg_prepare($conn,"insertar_dir",array($nombre, $puesto, $plaza, $f_ocupar, $clave_dir));
            echo json_encode(["success"=>1]);
        }
    }
    exit();
    break;
}
```

Cuando cambio la linea del insert y coloco el valor del id_dir como nulo me arroja lo siguiente:

```
$insert = pg_prepare($conn,"insertar_dir" ,"INSERT INTO directivos (id_dir,nombre, puesto, plaza, f_ocupar, clave_dir) VALUES($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6)");

$insert = pg_prepare($conn,"insertar_dir",array(null,$nombre, $puesto, $plaza, $f_ocupar, $clave_dir));
```

> Warning:  pg_prepare(): Query failed: ERROR:  no se puede insertar un valor no-predeterminado en la columna «id_dir»
> DETAIL:  La columna "id_dir" es una columna de identidad definida como GENERATED ALWAYS.
> HINT:  Use OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE para controlar manualmente.

Comment: Eduardo no pongas la clave  vaya en el insert sobra el **id_dir** ya que es una clave primaría en la tabla y encima autoincremental te lo pondrá automáticamente.

Comment: Encontré el error, resulta que el segundo $insert puse nuevamente pg_prepare, cuando debe ser pg_execute